# cannot find -lbgi | codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, linker, bgi

I'm trying to write some program with the legendary `graphics.h`

I got a toy code. And downloaded all necessary files:

- winbgim.h
- graphics.h
- libbgi.a

And then fixed all header bugs. And tried to compile with proper linking.

And the build log looks something like this:

```
g++.exe  -c C:\tem\1.cpp -o C:\tem\1.o
g++.exe  -o C:\tem\1.exe C:\tem\1.o  -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32  C:\tem\libbgi.a
```

And the error says: **`C:/Program-Files-Soft/codeblocks-20.03mingw-nosetup/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lbgi`**

Comment: The bgi lib is an extremely outdated resource for 16-bit raw graphics, are you sure that you want that, and if so, did you install it properly for your environment?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i use qt for gui and sdl like libraries.. and my work is around Ubuntu... but due to some requirements, I was trying to make it work somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > gcc (QP MinGW32) 4.4.5, 32 bit

I had tried different compiler, but nothing worked:

- gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
- gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
- there were 4 more

But the thing that resolved this is:
**`gcc (QP MinGW32) 4.4.5`**, and this build was for 32-bit although my system is 64-bit. And for some reason, this works. Without any crash or worse blue screen.

As @πάνταῥεῖ  mentioned this is really old, and the source code and build are from 2010.

And here is a completely portable version of Codeblocks IDE: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/codeblocks-ep. Everything should work. Else feel free to open an issue or pull.